# How can i apply data caching in metro style app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have  created metro style  Grid Application   which preview  data that i get it from web service ,but it's so bad in performance and make app so slow , i want to cache data that i get from web service to improve performance
any help ,
thanks  in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you seen [Simon Ince's article on caching results from a webservice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/10/20/offline-data-cache-in-windows-phone-7.aspx) (albeit for Windows Phone, much of the techniques could be reapplied to a metro app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SQLite to store the data. Here's an article on how to do that in a WinRT app: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/05/20/using-sqlite-in-metro-style-app.aspx

What you would cache depends on the type of data and usage scenarios of your app, but you can store your data in the SQLite store and try to get it from there if you are offline or simply before you do try to get it from the web service.